# Group and count results by day and hour

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a datetime column, an integer and a string one. Each time an event happen it gets save to the db with date and time:

```
datetime               plate    gateId
2013-11-01 10:42:45    qweqe    50
2013-11-01 10:44:00    sdfsd    51
2013-11-01 11:42:45    wewwe    50
```

What I want is to output a sum of how many rows i saved by hour and day for a given gateId, so for day 01 of month 11 between 10 and 11 for gateId 50 i got two rows.

I know how to sum the total, like `Select COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE gateId=50` but in this way i dont have the time division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` `date` and `hour` of the `datetime` column.

**Example**:

```
Select datetime, COUNT(*) cnt 
FROM table 
WHERE gateId=50
group by date( datetime ), hour( datetime )
```